# Prompting for a password on sudo?

Tags: sudo, users, group, amazon-ec2, puppet

I'm creating users using Puppet. Here's the gist of what I'm doing in Puppet:

```
user { 'ntkay':
    name => 'ntkay',
    uid  => 10000,
    home => '/home/ntkay',
    managehome => true,
    shell => '/bin/bash',
    groups => ['sudo', 'adm'],
}
```

This creates my user and I can log in with SSH using auth keys. However, when I do `sudo`, I see:

```
[sudo] password for ntkay:
```

The `ubuntu` user on this same system doesn't prompt for password on `sudo` and is member of the same groups. `ntkay` doesn't even have a password in the above configuration. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: `man sudo` `man sudoers`

Comment: I know that there's a `NOPASSWD` option, but _how is the `ubuntu` user doing sudo without a password?` The configuration is set to allow anyone in the `sudo` group to `%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`, but that presumes a password is present. How does `ubuntu` bypass this?

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay are you use there is nothing in `/etc/sudoers.d`, such as something placed by `cloud-init`?

Comment: @jordanm Please submit this as an answer and you'll have my upvote and the accepted answer. (contents of 90-cloud-init-users is `ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to `/etc/sudoers`, `sudo` will also read files in the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory. The `cloud-init` application, commonly used on AWS instances, places a `sudoers` configuration in that directory for allowing the default user to `sudo` without a password.

Comment: Please note that the directory may appear empty, but it might not be: directory permissions are `drwxr-x---`, meaning that if you're not `root:root`, you can't `ls` it.